# Silverlight can't show dropbox images

Tags: silverlight

This is how I set images in Silverlight:

```
 Public Sub setImage(ByRef img As Image, ByVal nameWithExtension As String, ByVal uriKind As UriKind)

    If uriKind = System.UriKind.Relative Then
        img.Source = New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(New Uri("/PortalSilver;component/Images/" & nameWithExtension, uriKind))
    Else
        img.Source = New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(New Uri(nameWithExtension, uriKind))
    End If

End Sub
```

I almost always use Absolute URIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a cross-scheme restriction between HTTP and HTTPS. Luckily, dropbox allows HTTP protocol.

Comment: as of at least 2015 dropbox no longer allows http.